# How to get the status message set by http_response_code in PHP

Tags: php, httpresponse

The `http_response_code` function sets the header to the defined code and corresponding message from this map [http_status_codes.h](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/http_status_codes.h).

Is it possible to get the message?

Comment: Are you referring to this?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php

Comment: yes, this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Apache, you may try with `apache_request_headers()`. Otherwise, that information might well not be available at all (i.e. sent directly to whatever HTTP serving tier is there, out-of-band and unseen from ob_* functions).

I don't think a definite general answer is possible without delving into the actual source code though.